# What are the current reliable remote internet options?

Tags: wifi, remote-access

I have a remote camera security system that is off-grid & solar-powered. Right now, I connect to it using a off-the-shelf mifi / hotspot device. It works, but if I ever have a few days of low light or just a glitch, the hotspot has no way of resetting itself. I actually have to go there and reset it manually. What other options are out there for getting reliable connectivity to this remote location?

Comment: you could add some small circuit that turns off the power everyday at say, 1PM and turns it back at 1:01PM. Perhaps that will help reset it in case of a brownout, etc.

Comment: Or just some circuitry that has hysterisis so that only when battery voltage is higher than say, 10v, it turns on, but turns off if the battery voltage goes below 9v
Something like [this_product](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07B49T4DQ/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_WHVJY8DKWMGZMRBPRPSR?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1). (I am not affiliated and dont know if this is reliable. Just googled it)

Comment: Use a proper cellular router rather than a consumer mifi